# Laravel format datetime

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, format

I have in my database the date of birth of a user, but I want to format that to something like 27 March 2000. I already have the date of registered and I can format that, but if I try to format the date of birth it gives me the following error:
**Call to a member function format() on string**

This code I used to show and format the date of birth of a user:

```
{{ucfirst(Auth::user()->created_at->format("M d Y"))}}
```

I tried to use this code for the date of birth because it is in a table with all the users:

```
{{ucfirst($user->birthdate->format("M d Y"))}}
```

This is the database structure:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agchg.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell Laravel that your `birthdate` field is a date, otherwise Laravel will just fetch it as-is and not touch it at all. You do that by adding a `protected $dates` to the model-class which is an array of all fields which Laravel should treat as dates.

```
class MyModel extends [...] {
    protected $dates = ['bithdate'];
}
```

This will tell Laravel that `birthdate` is a date and Laravel will convert it to a instance of `Carbon`.

Comment: Yes, see [Date Mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)